# Getting an id of an ruby object with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

So i have ruby code that simply writes all of my objects down in some view

```
%ul
    - @user.posts.each do |post|
        %li {data: {role: "choosable-post"}}
            = post.title
```

Now the trick is those are not posts itself, just the titles. how can i get the id of a specific post with jQuery? Of course `User has_many :posts` so every post has an id of its own.

i figured it could start like this...

```
$("li[data-role=choosable-post]").onclick ->
    my_object = @(this)
```

but i dont really know if its a good direction or how to continue if it is...

Comment: Does the `post` have an id attribute in ruby? If so then do what they say below.

Comment: jQuery runs client-side, and only has access to the DOM, barring AJAX. Ruby runs server-side, and will have finished its execution long before the browser starts executing any JavaScript. The two cannot interact directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already using data fields, it's extremely common to store information about objects in there:

```
%ul
  - @user.posts.each do |post|
    %li {data: {role: "choosable-post", id: "#{post.id}"}}
      = post.title
```

Now it's in the element you select, so it should be something like:

```
$("li[data-role=choosable-post]").onclick ->
  my_object_id = $(this).data('id')
```

That JavaScript is untested, but should give you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
%ul
  - @user.posts.each do |post|
    %li {data: {role: "choosable-post", id: "#{post.id}"}}
      = post.title
```

Will give you the `id`, and then, in your HTML, you should be able to find the `id` as shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gG2gs/2/

Answer (score 0):

render the post id into a data attribute

```
%li {class: "post-container", data: {role: "choosable-post", post-id: post.id}}
```

retrieve that client side with jquery

```
$(".post-container").click ->
  li = $(this)
  console.log(li.data('post-id'))
```